# How to Change the map view to new marker location in Flutter_map

Tags: flutter, location, markers, fluttermap

I'm using Flutter_map package and MapBox API for my app, I'm able to locate the current user location in the map but I want to put a button on the map and change the View of it to a new position when the user clicks on it (new location predefined as a marker 'secondPosition' in my code),
by the way, I know how to do it in the Google Maps package but I have no idea how to do it in flutter_map.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_location_marker/flutter_map_location_marker.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as latLng;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',

      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String  currentPosition = 'my Position';
  latLng.LatLng school = latLng.LatLng(37.2560129, 49.5855304);

  late CenterOnLocationUpdate _centerOnLocationUpdate;
  late StreamController<double?> _centerCurrentLocationStreamController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _determinePosition();
    _centerOnLocationUpdate = CenterOnLocationUpdate.always;
    _centerCurrentLocationStreamController = StreamController<double?>();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _centerCurrentLocationStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }



  _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Please enable Your Location Service');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg:
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {

      currentPosition =
      " lat=${position.latitude} long=${position.longitude}";

    });

    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$currentPosition ');
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Marker SecondPosition = Marker(
      anchorPos: AnchorPos.align(AnchorAlign.top),

      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
      point:  school,
      builder: (ctx) =>
          Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined,size: 30,color: Colors.red,),
    );


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(

            center: school,
            zoom: 17,
            onPositionChanged: (MapPosition position, bool hasGesture) {
              if (hasGesture) {
                setState(
                      () => _centerOnLocationUpdate = CenterOnLocationUpdate.never,
                );
              }
            },
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayerWidget(options: TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate:
                "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/badsina/cl10kxiip004y16sxae7s7uyo/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk."
                    "eyJ1IjoiYmFkc2luYSIsImEiOiJjbDEwa2p2b3oxemc3M2JrYm9jZ3d0eHFvIn0.j5mmEFjIz41ZF3ATSXEVAg",
                additionalOptions: {
                  'accessToken':
                  'pk.eyJ1IjoiYmFkc2luYSIsImEiOiJjbDEwa2p2b3oxemc3M2JrYm9jZ3d0eHFvIn0.j5mmEFjIz41ZF3ATSXEVAg',
                  'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8'
                }),),

            LocationMarkerLayerWidget(

              plugin: LocationMarkerPlugin(
                centerCurrentLocationStream:
                _centerCurrentLocationStreamController.stream,
              ),
            ),
          ],
          nonRotatedChildren: [
            Positioned(
              right: 20,
              bottom: 20,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Automatically center the location marker on the map when location updated until user interact with the map.
                  setState(
                        () => _centerOnLocationUpdate = CenterOnLocationUpdate.always,
                  );
                  // Center the location marker on the map and zoom the map to level 18.
                  _centerCurrentLocationStreamController.add(18);
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.my_location,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to center the map to a new location, just add mapController,  and use the move function to set the new center locations.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   ...
   late MapController _mapController;
   ...
   @override
   void initState() {
     ...
     _mapController = MapController();
   }
   ...
   void someFunction() {
     _mapController.move(latLng.LatLng(someLang, someLon), 18.0);
   }
   ...
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ...
     return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(

    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(

        center: school,
        zoom: 17,
        onPositionChanged: (MapPosition position, bool hasGesture) {
          if (hasGesture) {
            setState(
                  () => _centerOnLocationUpdate = CenterOnLocationUpdate.never,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      mapController: _mapController,
      children: [
        ...
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
 ...
}
```